# How to select all records from SQL database and put it in Listview Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, listview

Im trying to learn how to store and get record from a database for android application, i can do update, insert, delete etc. but i have problem in getting more than one record, I want to ask how to get all records from a table in localhost phpmyadmin and export the result into the listview in android application using shared preferences, here is my php function code:

```
 public function getLessons($teacher) {

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM lessons WHERE teacher = :teacher';
$query = $this -> conn -> prepare($sql);
$query -> execute(array(':teacher' => $teacher));
$data = $query -> fetchObject();

$lesson["title"] = $data -> title; // im not sure if this is true
$lesson["maxstudent"] = $data -> maxstudent; // im not sure if this is true       
$lesson["about"] = $data -> about; // im not sure if this is true
return $lesson;// the result of sql query will be more than one record 
}
```

the code above will retrieve the result of query, but im not sure about the code, what is the result of lesson if the result is more than one record? is that an array of string?and here is my java method to get all lesson in the database code:

```
        private void getLessonProcess(String teacher){

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        RequestInterface requestInterface = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);

        Lesson lesson = new Lesson();// its Java Class containing title,maxstudent and about
        lesson.setTeacher(teacher);// we set the teacher, so only specific teacher's lesson will be given as a result
        ServerRequest request = new ServerRequest();// server request is a class to connect to localhost
        request.setOperation(Constants.LESSONS);// constants.LESSONS is 'getlessons' the key that i use to trigger the SQL Query above
        request.setLesson(lesson);
        Call<ServerResponse> response = requestInterface.operation(request);

        response.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<ServerResponse> response) {

                ServerResponse resp = response.body();
                Snackbar.make(getView(), resp.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                  if(resp.getResult().equals(Constants.SUCCESS)){
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                        editor.putString(Constants.LESSONS,resp.getLesson().getLessontitle());
                        editor.putString(???,resp.getLesson().getMaxstudent());
                        editor.putString(???,resp.getLesson().getAbout());
                        ?????????? // What should i write here?
                        //in code above it will only put one record of the database and put it in shared preference 
                        editor.apply();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                    Log.d(Constants.TAG,"failed");
                    Snackbar.make(getView(), t.getLocalizedMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();                 

            }
        });
    }
```

is that possible to iterate through all the data and put it in an arraylist so that i can use adapter to show the result in ListView? Thank You

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME
            + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + key_msg + " STRING, " + key_isread + " STRING)");


}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

//*************************-------INSERT GCM MESSAGE---------**************************//

```
public void insert_GCM_receive_data(String msg) {

    String value;
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put(key_msg, msg);
    cv.put(key_isread, "N");

    value = cv.toString();

    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    System.out.println("/n******this is temp table name  " + TABLE_NAME + "\nthis is temp msg  " + cv + "\nmsg" + msg + "\nval" + value);

    db.close();

}
```

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

//**********************----------GET ALERT DATA------------**************************//
    public ArrayList get_alert_msg() {

```
    ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c = null;
        c = db.rawQuery("SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);

        System.out.println(c);

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {

            String str_id = c.getString(0);
            String str_msg = c.getString(1);
            String str_read = c.getString(2);
            Log.e("value", str_id + str_msg + str_read);

            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
            hm.put("msg", str_msg);
            hm.put("isread", str_read);


            name.add(str_msg);


        }
        c.close();
        db.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("this not work", "" + e);
    }

    return name;
}`
```

//call method like

dbHelper = new Database_for_Received_data(this.getActivity());
            name= new ArrayList(dbHelper.get_alert_msg());

Use query like "select * from table_name".... Then extend SQLiteopenhelper in your database class.

It's from using data storing, getting and manipulating purpose..

Answer (score 0):

If your data is stored in database server (Mysql, oracle etc) , you will have to first write a web service in Php. That particular service will extract all your data from the database. Then you have to write a web logic which will convert your extracted data into xml or json as only these formats of data can travel in the network. If you have multipe data then you can also make json array from that data. 
When android client will call your web service through Retrofit, it will automatically get json in the response of the same. That json can be parsed into the ArrayList class of java. Now you can show all of your data in ListView by following the basic steps to populate list data into the ListView.